# Append text with Date in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to append Text field with Date in Excel Sheet. I have a text format like this.

**9/23/99 10:37am We're not going. I'm on disablity. Columbus is not the thriving place. It's mostly retired military. She called to ask why she is the only one. Wanted her partner on, too. I explained that happens in the meeting. 9/10/99 4:15p Rick Ludwig referred $995 Wants Essex Funding & Associates Inc. WY 4262-3607-0011-9582 8/01 8/23/99 9:08am Want a NV corporation. Need to do a little bit of finance change around. A couple of the programs. MU and mentors. Parters and I...I am 60. I maxxed out my cards yesterday.**

So I want to append some data when my date field will come into picture

for example

**"HTML Paragraph Tag"9/23/99 10:37am We're not going. I'm on disablity. Columbus is not the thriving place. It's mostly retired military. She called to ask why she is the only one. Wanted her partner on, too. I explained that happens in the meeting. "End of HTML Paragraph Tag" "HTML Paragraph Tag" 9/10/99 No Need to worry**

Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Use the & symbol? Formula: `=A1&Today()`. Or just do almost exactly the same in VBA: `activecell.value=activecell.value & date()`. I don't understand what your question is here.

Comment: you mean split not append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarifications

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim newStrng As String
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim strngToBeAppended As String

    strngToBeAppended = Application.InputBox("Input string to be appended", 1)

    With Worksheets("TextSheet") '<-- change "TextSheet" to your actual sheet with text name
        For Each word In Split(.Range("A1").Text, " ") '<-- assuming that the text to be splitted is in cell "A1" of the referenced worksheet
            If Len(word) - Len(Replace(word, "/", "")) = 2 Then
                newStrng = newStrng & " " & strngToBeAppended & word
            Else
                newStrng = newStrng & " " & word
            End If
        Next word
        .Range("A2").Value = LTrim(newStrng)
    End With
End Sub
```

as you see:

- the "text to be appended" is requested to the user by means of an `Application.InputBox()` call
- the "text to append to" is assumed in cell "A1" of worksheet "TextSheet"
- the "output" text is written in cell "A2" of worksheet "TextSheet"

you can change all those references to your actual needs

Comment: too vague a sentence. give details about: starting data, what's not working and how's not working.

Comment: I have a requirement like, I want to append the text before my Date for example "9/23/99 10:37am We're not going" before the date like 9/23/99 I want to append some text

Comment: so you want: 1) define/input a "date" (for example "9/23/99") 2) search a "text" for that "date" 3) have "some other text" being input 4) insert that "some other text" _before_ the "date" in the "text". Should it be like that: a) where is the "date" to be read from? b) where is the "text" to be read from? c) where is the "some other text" to be read from?

Comment: Yes, I want 1.Search the Date from the Text 2.I want to Insert the text which will <p> and </p> before the Text . a.Date to be read from the Text. b. text is in the column. c) Other Data will be hardcoded.

Comment: sorry but I'm not getting you. the best is you enhance your post with a clear example of a "before" and "after" scenario as well as with details about where all relevant data are to be get and/or written

Comment: _"it is not working"_ is too vague a sentence. If you want help, you need to provide all possible information about: input data (read from where, its value), output data (written where, its value) and description of what didn't work

Comment: bring with me: I want to know if my answer worked as per your _original_ question. As per this site rules you can't update a question if not to improve (adding examples, data, screenshots) its understanding but not changing the _original_ request. And, should the OP need to change the _original_  question, he/she would post a new one. Otherwise, as you may agree, there would be no ending ... Bottom line:Ilet me know if my answer worked as per your _original_ question and, if not, explain with proper detail what's "not working" _actually_ means

Comment: As per my original question answer is working fine. Now the problem is I want to append html tag when i found date in that String with proper opening and closing of the tag. i.e. if my string is like "23/06/1992 Hello world Note is created 23/4/1991 Note Has been Changed" ---- should be converted to------ "<p> 23/06/1992 Hello world Note is created </p> <p>23/4/1991 Note Has been Changed</p>"

Comment: Since my answer solved your _original_ question, please mark it as accepted (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). as to new issues you have to make a new post along with your coding efforts and a clear explanation as to how is your posted code not working